# How to Fix a Reference not resolved exception on vb.net Project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, unit-testing, enterprise-library

I'm working on a VB.net Test Project using «Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common», «Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging» and «Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler».
When i launch the unit any unitTest a get this exception :

> 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' cannot be resolved. Please verify the spelling is correct or that the full type name is provided.

And after that i get this error from visual studioi 2017 :
[image]

This is the full stack of the exception :
[image]

Comment: When i push the project into TFS 2018 and execute a Build, it works fine !

Comment: No Body is here... ? I need a help please

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, in visual studio, Test Tab i had a file test settings is checked, just uncheck this option and every things will work like a cheep in the water :)